# SQL Job Scheduler UI in silverlight

Tags: sql-server

I use this query to get the values of a job and display it in a silverlight control. The UI is exactly like the SQL Job Scheduler UI. But I having hard time deciphering the numeric values in sysschedules to UI Elements.

Especially the week, each value is multiplied by itself and 2. For eg, Sunday=1, Monday=2, Tuesday=4, Wed=8, Thu=16, Fri=32, Sat=64.
In sysschedules it's stored in combination of the values. For eg, if Fri and Sat are checked the freq_interval=96 (64+32), if all the days are checked it's value would be 127.

My question is, is there a formula or something to know what days are selected using the numeric value.

```
 SELECT   
  schedule_id  
  ,schedule_uid  
  ,originating_server_id  
  ,name  
  ,owner_sid  
  ,enabled  
  ,freq_type  
  ,freq_interval  
  ,freq_subday_type  
  ,freq_subday_interval  
  ,freq_relative_interval  
  ,freq_recurrence_factor  
  ,dbo.FormatDate(active_start_date) as active_start_date  
  ,dbo.FormatDate(active_end_date) as active_end_date  
  ,dbo.FormatTime(active_start_time) as active_start_time  
  ,dbo.FormatTime(active_end_time) as active_end_time  
  ,date_created  
  ,date_modified  
  ,version_number  
 FROM msdb.dbo.sysschedules WHERE schedule_id=@scheduleId
```

Comment: See if this artical helps you http://solihinho.wordpress.com/2009/01/01/query-for-listing-sql-server-job-schedule/

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You have described the formula yourself in your question??

Comment: Well, for eg., if the value is 26, how would I know what days are checked. By looking at the table I can tell that Mon, Wed and Thu are checked, but how can I do it in code? That's what I'm having trouble.

Comment: @Bruce - awesome, this is exactly what I want. How do I mark it as Answer

Comment: I've added it as an answer so you can mark it.  Glad that helped, and thanks for the feedback.